# How to populate details fragment with content provider from list fragment

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a ListFragment that populates a list using a SimpleCursorAdapter.  It is using a two pane setup to show the details fragment on the right side.

```
public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        string[] fromColumns = new string[]
        {
            MinefieldDataProvider.InterfaceConsts.FirstName
        };

        int[] toControlIds = new int[]
        {
            Android.Resource.Id.Text1
        };

        LoaderManager.InitLoader(PersonnelListLoaderId, null, this);
        this._adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Activity.ApplicationContext, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null, fromColumns, toControlIds, CursorAdapterFlags.None);
        this.ListAdapter = this._adapter;
    }

    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            View detailsPane = this.Activity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.item_detail_container);
            this._dualPane = (detailsPane != null && detailsPane.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible);

            if (savedInstanceState != null)
                this._currentPosition = savedInstanceState.GetInt("currentPosition", -1);

            if (this._dualPane)
            {
                this.ListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
                this.ShowDetails(this._currentPosition);
            }
        }
```

However I'm unsure of the "android "way" in which to populate the details pane with the user selection.  Do I extract the URI and pass it to the details fragment and then use a new instance of the ContentProvider in the details section?  Or do I pass along each individual field that I want to show up in the user interface somehow?

Note that in the details pane the user will be able to edit the information and save it via a button using the ContentProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a loader manager in the details fragment and queried there.  It's more self contained that way.